# Create buttons inside clickable div

Tags: javascript, html

I have clickable div, made by addEventListener on element:

```
function expandTask() {
    const allTasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task-item');

    allTasks.forEach((task) => {
        task.addEventListener("click", () => {
                if(!task.classList.contains('active')){
                    task.classList.add('active');
                } else {
                    task.classList.remove('active')
                }
            })
    })
}
```

and I would like to put some buttons inside this clickable div, how can i make this work?

When i click on button, it still consider this as click on parent div.

Comment: Event bubbles by default. So if you include a button inside a div, it bubbles to the parent div and triggers the handler. So no need to do any extra thing, just make a button inside the div. But I don't know why you would want a clickable div, and a button inside it.

Comment: Do you want the button click to do something different than the div click?

Comment: @DipeshTimilsina While creating todo app, i have tasks lists and clicking on task expand more details, and on this task i want buttons like checkbox that make task complete, edit button or delete task.

Answer (score 1):

You can create elements dynamically using `document.createElement(tagName)` and then use `element.appendChild(element)` to insert them in the document.

Bonus: you can use `classList.toggle(className)` if that suits your needs.

```
function expandTask() {
    const allTasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task-item');

    allTasks.forEach((task) => {
        task.addEventListener("click", () => {
            task.classList.toggle('active');

            let newDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
            newDiv.innerHTML = "Some text you want to add";
            task.appendChild(newDiv);
        });
    })
}
```

Edit: as said in the comments, the event bubbles up by default, you can understand more about it [here](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)